# i'm getting an error while updating a targeted article

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, rest

i'm trying to create a simple RestAPI, and while i use putting or updating a perticualr element it didnt upate anything. i use postman to update it.

```
    .put(function(req, res){

  Article.updateOne(
    {title: req.params.articleTitle},
    {title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content},
    {overwrite: true},
    function(err){
      if (!err){
        res.send("Successfully updated the content of the selected article.");
      }else{
        res.send(err);
      }
    }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `{overwrite: true}` and your code works.

P.S: According to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#update you shouldn't use `overwrite` option in updateOne